# Prevent Over Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

After studying, looking at tutorials, getting some help here, I almost got this script working as intended. However, I'm not at a stand still and my brain hurts trying to figure out the logic.

The problem is the script allows for over scrolling forward. How can I stop that?

jQuery:

```
var $item = $('.slider'),
    start = 0,
    view = $('#main-header').width(),
    end = $('.slider').width();

$('.next').click(function () {
    if (start < view) {
        start++;
        $item.animate({
            'left': '-=100%'
        });
    }
});

$('.prev').click(function () {
    if (start > 0) {
        start--;
        $item.animate({
            'left': '+=100%'
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main-header">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="item-post" style="background: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-LjJWOy7K-Q0/VOUJbMJr0_I/AAAAAAAAdAg/I2V70xea8YE/s320-c/enviroment-5.jpg) center"></div>
        <div class="item-post" style="background: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-l3UnbspFvv0/VOUK8M-34UI/AAAAAAAAdA0/ooGyXrHdNcg/s320-c/enviroment-2.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="item-post" style="background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-cun1kQ42IBs/VOUaSPfnebI/AAAAAAAAdBQ/yTEj9K-BGdk/s320-c/fashion-3.jpg)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="prev"></div>
    <div class="next"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-header {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.item-post {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.item-post:first-of-type {
    left: 0;
}
.item-post:nth-of-type(2) {
    left: 100%;
}
.item-post:last-of-type {
    left: 200%;
}
.prev, .next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 25px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.prev {
    left: 0;
}
.next {
    right: 0;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/51maaks8/8/

Comment: What do you mean by "over scrolling"? Do you want to stop sliding when reaching the end? Or you do want infinite scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to determine whether there is another slide visible, you could create a function that adds the `.offsetLeft` value of the parent element to the `.offsetLeft` value of the *last* visible slide element *and* its width. You would then subtract the width of the parent element from the sum of these calculations.

In doing so, you are essentially calculating the position of the last slide element *relative* to the left positioning of the `.item-wrapper` parent element.

```
function moreVisibleSlides() {
    var $last = $('#slider > .item-wrapper > .item-post:last:visible'),
        positionRelativeToParent = $last.parent()[0].offsetLeft + $last[0].offsetLeft + $last.width() - $item.width();

    return positionRelativeToParent > 5;
}
```

For the click event listener, only slide the element if there are more visible slides, which is determined by the boolean returned by the `moreVisibleSlides` function. In addition, I also added a check (`!$item.is(':animated')`) to prevent the next slide from being animated if there is currently an animation in progress. This ensures that you can't click the `.next` button multiple times during an animation and then over scroll regardless of whether or not there are more visible slides.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/r5r32cy3/)

```
$('.next').click(function () {
    if (moreVisibleSlides() && !$item.is(':animated')) {
        start++;
        $item.animate({
            'left': '-=100%'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This won't work for me because of responsive design. In mobile there are 3 items, in desktop there are 5 items per viewport totaling 15 items. Total width is 300% of parent element. I tried `total =  view * 3-1, but that didn't work either.

Comment: This fiddle posted here shows mobile view, here is desktop view: http://jsfiddle.net/ytj8t9nr/2/

Comment: @Xarcell Alright--in that case, you could use the following: http://jsfiddle.net/ww6Lgeyn/ it works for both mobile/desktop views. It basically checks to see the offset position of the last visible slider *relative* to the parent element.

Comment: @Xarcell Mobile - http://jsfiddle.net/o6nvow4p/ ... and desktop - http://jsfiddle.net/ww6Lgeyn/ .. both of which are using the same script.

Comment: Thanks for you help. This looks like it would work. Although, I had to make a few changes, which lead me to make changes to the script you made. It works fine in the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ww6Lgeyn/1/ . However, when I try to apply it to my template, it still doesn't limit scrolling to the right. The css is almost identical(only height is different), but the script behaves differently and I need time to investigate why that is.

Comment: @Xarcell That's interesting. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I will have to investigate further, but it seems to only happen in Firefox, not Chrome, or IE. Even though it works fine with the fiddle script in FF. I'm thinking it's gotta be CSS related? There are no errors in the consoles.

Comment: I can't figure out why this is happening. Works fine in the fiddle, but when used in a live template, in FF it still allows over-scrolling. In the inspector, if I disable `overflow:hidden`, there is no extra space to the right. So I don't get where the extra space is coming from unless it's the javascript itself.

Comment: @Xarcell Maybe you could post another question? I'd take a look

Comment: Well, the problem is still the same. No prevention of over-scrolling. Should I still post another question? Latest working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ww6Lgeyn/4/ which works as expected. However, in the template you can still over-scroll in FF, but the CSS is almost identical to the fiddle: http://xarcell-studios-jubilation-template.blogspot.com/

Comment: @Xarcell I figured it out. It had to do with how Firefox rounded the `px` units. Apparently that works different between browsers. Also, I found another issue where it wouldn't work after resizing the browser. I was able to fix both of those issues.. here is an updated example.. http://jsfiddle.net/r5r32cy3/

Comment: This is good news. I tested it and everything seems to be in order. If you update your answer I will accept it. Thanks for your help by the way. Highly appreciated.